# How to assign my machine static IP of a different VLAN

Tags: networking, ip

Imagine a user is on VLAN1 that dynamically gets an IP, and there is a VLAN2 that the users on VLAN1 cannot access.

Is there a way to assign the machine of user on VLAN1 an static IP in the range of VLAN2 IPs to access the resources on VLAN2?

To set up the static IP in the Network connections under IP version 4 properties, what would you set for subnet mask, and DNS settings?

Comment: Have you researched to see how VLANs operate? It's not the IP that's at issue, but the routing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to figure out how to assign the client to correct VLAN. This is NOT done via the IP, but further down in the stack (I cannot remember which layer, but i think it's 2). A common option here is 802.1q, a.k.a. Tag based VLAN. Basically, the switch connecting the client will treat anything connected to a specific port as belonging to a specific VLAN. Now that you in effect have two vlans up and running (or one VLAN + an untagged aspect of the network, depending on how you look at it)

The second step is to ensure that any devices between the tagging switch and the server is forwarding the tagged packets as intended. Basically, enabling the same vlans on the other switches as well.

Thirdly, the server needs to be on both VLANS - Both the "special one", and the untagged one. This is very OS specific, so I won't go into that, but to put it simply, you'll need two DHCP servers running, one binding to each vlan-specific interface, so that it can serve leases for both of them.

Fourthly (is that a word?), once everything above is set up, and confirmed working, you can assign a static lease in the DHCP server covering the tagged portion of the network.

As for the specifics you asked about, the DNS and mask settings, these should be the same for both VLANS. VLANS operate on a much lower level, so these settings are not affected by it.